# Show the relation "$\leq$" on $\mathbb{R}$ is a total order.

Tags: order-theory, real-numbers

How can I show that the [partial relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrder.html) "$\leq$" on $\mathbb{R}$ is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). It seems obvious to me, but I cannot argue that.

Can you show this result for real numbers?

At a first step, assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is partially ordered. How can I prove that the set of real numbers is totally ordered?

Comment: You can't prove anything without a definition.  How do you define $\mathbb{R}$ and how do you define $\leq$?

Comment: How do you construct real numbers and its order?

Comment: If you want a complete answer for it, you must to see how the real numbers are built with Dedekind's cuts or Cauchy sequences. I think that it is the formal way to do it.